# When is an enumerator useful?

Tags: ruby, enumerator

An `Enumerator` object can be created by calling certain methods without passing a block, for example [Array#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-reject):

```
(1..3).reject.to_a
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

Is this just some rule of ruby for easier chaining or is there some other way to pass behavior to the Enumerator?

Comment: " is there some other way to pass behavior to the Enumerator?" - not sure what you meant by this.

Comment: I don't disagree with your decision to award the greenie to @Sergio, but next time consider waiting awhile (at least of a couple of hours, say) before making a decision. A quick selection (here about 25 minutes after you posted the question) can discourage other answers and is not appreciated by those still working on their answers. Even if subsequent answers are not "better", they may contain useful observations which you may be able to apply in other situations. There's no rush.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this just some rule of ruby for easier chaining

Yes, this reason exactly. Easy chaining of enumerators. Consider this example:

```
ary = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Eve']

records = ary.map.with_index do |item, idx|
  {
    id: idx,
    name: item,
  }
end

records # => [{:id=>0, :name=>"Alice"}, {:id=>1, :name=>"Bob"}, {:id=>2, :name=>"Eve"}]
```

`map` yields each element to `with_index`, which slaps item index on top of it and yields to your block. Block returns value to `with_index`, which returns to `map` which (*does its thing, the mapping, and*) returns to caller.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this just some rule of ruby for easier chaining

It's not a rule of Ruby. It's just that the `reject` method (for example) returns an `Enumerator` if called without a block. It could do something else instead.

> or is there some other way to pass behavior to the `Enumerator`?

Yes, the `Enumerator` encapsulates the behavior of the method you created the `Enumerator` from. For example, creating an `Enumerator` from `reject` creates an object which will reject some of its elements. `Enumerator` mixes in `Enumerable`, so can do with this `Enumerator` anything you can do with any other `Enumerable`. For example:

```
enum = (1..3).reject

enum.with_index {|el, i| i.even? }
# => [2]
```

Comment: Nice example of being able to pass reject behavior to the enum.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sergio says, it's mainly for chaining, but it goes beyond that. If you have an enumerator, `e`, you can extract elements with [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and [Enumerator#peek](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next). Here are two examples of how enumerators can be used to advantage.

**Problem:** given an array `a`, construct another array whose value at index `i` is `a[i]` if `i` is odd and `2*a[i]` if `i` is even. Suppose `a = [1,2,3,4]`.

One would commonly see:

```
a.map.with_index { |n,i| n.odd? ? n : 2*n } #=> [1,4,3,8]
```

but this could also be written:

```
e = [1,2].cycle          #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2]:cycle> 
a.map { |n| e.next * n } #=> [1, 4, 3, 8]
```

**Problem:** given an array `a`, chunk consecutive values that are equal into arrays. Let me make this statement more precise by showing how it would commonly be done. Suppose `a = [1,1,2,3,3,3,4]`.

```
a.chunk(&:itself).map(&:last) #=> [[1, 1], [2], [3, 3, 3], [4]]
```

In Ruby v2.2 (where [#itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-itself) made its debut), you could use [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when):

```
a.slice_when { |f,l| f != l }.to_a
  #=> [[1, 1], [2], [3, 3, 3], [4]]
```

but you could also use an enumerator:

```
e = a.to_enum
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]:each> 
b = [[]]
loop do
  n = e.next
  b[-1] << n
  nxt = e.peek
  b << [] if nxt != n
end
b
  #=> [[1, 1], [2], [3, 3, 3], [4]]
```

Note that when `n` is last value of `e`, `e.peek` will raise a `StopInteration` exception. That exception is handled by [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) by breaking out of the loop.

I'm not suggestion that this last method should be used in preference to the other two options I mentioned, but there are other situations where this sort of approach can be used effectively.

**One more thing:** if you have an expression of chained methods, you can examine the contents of the enumerator whose elements are passed to the block by converting the enumerator to an array. From that you can see what block variables are needed.  Suppose you wished to write:

```
[1,2,3,4].each_with_index.with_object({}) {....}
```

and do something in the block, but were unsure about how to express the block variables. You could do this:

```
e = [1,2,3,4].each_with_index.with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:each_with_index>
        :with_object({})> 
e.to_a
  #=> [[[1, 0], {}], [[2, 1], {}], [[3, 2], {}], [[4, 3], {}]]
```

This shows that (say) the first element of `e` passed to the block is:

```
[[1, 0], {}]
```

telling use that the block variables should be:

```
(n,i), h = [[1, 0], {}]
n #=> 1 
i #=> 0 
h #=> {}
```

meaning that the expression should be written:

```
[1,2,3,4].each_with_index.with_object({}) { |(n,i),h|....}
```